# why the filesystem is always “read-only” in my Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, readonly

When I reboot Ubuntu using the `reboot` command, the screen keeps going black. then I forced the shutdown to restart and went to the GRUB option(as shown in the below).

```
*Ulbuntu       # <------- enter “e”
Advanced opt ions for ubuntu
UEFI Firmware settings
```

Next, I press the `E` key:
[This is where things go wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMB5H.jpg) (I cannot post the picture,because i have not enough reputation)

I modified the red boxes, `ro -> rw` and add the second place with `nomodeset`. shown as below:
[here is After the modification picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axbhy.jpg)

finally, enter `F10` and then the screen appears after the boot interface.

But, what drives me crazy is that every time I reboot the machine. The problem arises again:
`rw` returns `ro`, the `nomodeset` disappeared.

> machine：Ubuntu 20.04;

> GNU GRUB version 2.04;

So, What can I do to avoid this situation? thanks a lot for your answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the grub command line actually is set to have ro specified, you can edit it in `/etc/default/grub` (eg. `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub` if you want this graphically). There you'll find a line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=....` where you can replace the `ro` with `rw`.

Afterwards you'll have to run `sudo update-grub` for the config to take effect.

Comment: These Settings do half the job. On my ubuntu, I have to add extra parameters `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.